# Concurrent array access with std::atomic

Tags: multithreading, c++11, atomic

I know how `mutex` synchronization works, but I have problems deciding how synchronization need to be done in following over simplified case:

We have an array with 10 elements.

`Thread 1` access the array in read only way - read elements. e.g. something like this:

```
// const int *my_array;
int something = my_array[5];
```

`Thread 2` doing unrelated stuff, but from time to time it might decide to update all 10 elements at once. e.g. something like:

```
// const int *my_array;
const int *my_temp_array = load_new_data();
// suppose pointer memory are correct.
// because it is pointers, the following operation is instant
my_array = my_temp_array;
```

Both threads need to use primitive such `std::unique_lock`.

But is there a way this to be done with `std::atomic`?

---

Note:
as Igor mentioned:

> if thread 1 loops over the array, and thread 2 flips it in the middle
>   of the loop - is it OK to process half old elements and half new ones?
>   Who allocates memory for the array, and when and by whom should it be
>   deallocated?

The example is oversimplified and I am interested only in general thread synchronization. This is why number of elements are fixed to 10. Also let suppose there is no memory allocation and it is OK to process half old elements and half new ones.

Comment: Your code should work as written if you make `my_array` to be `std::atomic<int*>`. "Work" here means it would be race-free. Whether it would implement the correct semantics is difficult to say without more details. E.g. if thread 1 loops over the array, and thread 2 flips it in the middle of the loop - is it OK to process half old elements and half new ones? Who allocates memory for the array, and when and by whom should it be deallocated?

Comment: `std::atomic<int*>` are you sure this is enough? I saw some lock free code that did busy wait with `std::atomic<bool>` e.g. something like `while(lock);` but it was terrible if you think what happen. I'll edit for memory.

Comment: In this simple example, once you wave away all the complications - yes, that's all you need.

Comment: Is the old memory freed?

Comment: It is educational code, suppose it is static memory.

Answer (score 0):

if old memory not need to free, `std::atomic<int*>`  works like this

```
//global atomic ptr
std::atomic<int*> myarray = nullptr;

// Thread 1
const int * current_array = myarray;
// do something current_array[10]
int something = current_array[5];

// Thread 2
int * tmp_array = new int[10];
myarray = tmp_array;
```